# How to print a letter of a word using a number?

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to coding and my teacher asked us to make a code for a hangman game. He told us that we must accomplish this without the use of Arrays. My question is along the lines of this: If I have a String that is declared by the user and then a correct  letter is guessed, how would I specifically be able to replace a substituted underscore with the guessed letter?

For example...

input is "cats"
system types "_ _ _ _"

say I typed the letter "a" and I want the output to be:

"_ a _ _" 
How would I get the placement number of that letter and then manipulate the underscore to make it the letter?

Comment: Keep it simple.  You could use four variables, one for each character.

Comment: But how would I do that if the number of characters is entirely reliant on whatever the person types?

Comment: Take a look at the String class in the Java API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html 

What have you tried?

Comment: How big is the longest word you are willing to accept?  a 40 character word?

Comment: technically, they can put whatever length they want, but for the sake of this project, the longest word will probably be around 9 characters

Answer (score 0):

[`StringBuilder.charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#charAt(int))

[`StringBuilder.setCharAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int,%20char))

You may want to have a look at these methods.

For the purpose of printing, you may want [`StringBuilder.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString()).

Answer (score 0):

You could use substrings. Something like this.

```
String original = "apple";
String guessed = original;
String withUnderscores = "_____";

String guess = "a";
while (guessed.contains(guess))
{
    int index = guessed.indexOf(guess);
    withUnderscores = withUnderscores.substring(0, index) + guess + withUnderscores.substring(index + 1);
    guessed = guessed.substring(0, index) + "." + guessed.substring(index + 1);
}

System.out.println(original);
System.out.println(guessed);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use one variable to store the underscore string. (ie "____"
- Use another variable to store the answer string. (ie "cats").
- Get the users input and and loop through the string taking the character at each index. If any variable matches the input letter (string1.equals(string2)) replace the character in the underscore string at whatever index your loop is at.

Use charAt() to get the character at a place in a string.

You can do this with a String or the StringBuilder class. If you haven't learned about StringBuilder in your classes, you probably shouldn't use it for your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I would prefer to have the guesses on a Set, it would be more clear than using a string to hold them):

```
   public String maskUnguessedLetters(String answer, String guessed) {
     Char MASKED = '_';
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     for (Char c : answer.toCharArray()) {
       sb.append(guessed.contains(c.toString())
                 ? c
                 : MASKED);
     }
     return sb.toString();
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't completely understand the question, but I think this might help.

```
final String trueWord="cats";
String guessWord="____";

String input="a";

//if the input matches
if(trueWord.contains(input)){

    //last Index of input in trueWord
    int lastEntry=-1;

    //hold all indices of input character in trueWord
    ArrayList<Integer> indices=new ArrayList<>();
    while(trueWord.indexOf(input,lastEntry+1) >= 0){
        lastEntry=trueWord.indexOf(input);
        indices.add(lastEntry);
    }

    //now replace the characters at the indices
    StringBuilder newGuessWord = new StringBuilder(guessWord);

    for(int index:indices){
        //replace one character at a time.
        newGuessWord.setCharAt(index, input.charAt(0));
    }
    //the new word
    guessWord=newGuessWord.toString();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the not the most optimised code but will definitely give you an idea of how your task can be done.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String word = "cats";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess the character");

    String finalString = "";
    char letter = scanner.next().charAt(0);

    for (char s : word.toCharArray()) {
        if (s == letter) {
            finalString += s;
        } else
            finalString += "_";
    }

    System.out.println(finalString);
    scanner.close();
}
```